# methods in an ejb session bean for an entity dont work in a spring MVC project

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, ejb, netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

I created a maven entreprise application project, in the ejb module i put my entities in a package and i generated my session beans in an other package and i deployed my ejb module in glassfish,in the web module i added dependencies of spring and I created a controller that search the session bean and call the methode find all() but it doesnt get my objects stored in database, what should i do?

Category entity

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author DELL
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "categorie")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Categorie.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Categorie c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Categorie.findByIdCategorie", query = "SELECT c FROM Categorie c WHERE c.idCategorie = :idCategorie"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Categorie.findByDescription", query = "SELECT c FROM Categorie c WHERE c.description = :description"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Categorie.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Categorie c WHERE c.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Categorie.findByNomPhoto", query = "SELECT c FROM Categorie c WHERE c.nomPhoto = :nomPhoto")})
public class Categorie implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idCategorie")
    private Integer idCategorie;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "nomPhoto")
    private String nomPhoto;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "photo")
    private byte[] photo;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idCategorie")
    private List<Produit> produitList;

    public Categorie() {
    }

    public Categorie(Integer idCategorie) {
        this.idCategorie = idCategorie;
    }

    public Integer getIdCategorie() {
        return idCategorie;
    }

    public void setIdCategorie(Integer idCategorie) {
        this.idCategorie = idCategorie;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNomPhoto() {
        return nomPhoto;
    }

    public void setNomPhoto(String nomPhoto) {
        this.nomPhoto = nomPhoto;
    }

    public byte[] getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Produit> getProduitList() {
        return produitList;
    }

    public void setProduitList(List<Produit> produitList) {
        this.produitList = produitList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idCategorie != null ? idCategorie.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Categorie)) {
            return false;
        }
        Categorie other = (Categorie) object;
        if ((this.idCategorie == null && other.idCategorie != null) || (this.idCategorie != null && !this.idCategorie.equals(other.idCategorie))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.mycompany.entities.Categorie[ idCategorie=" + idCategorie + " ]";
    }

}
```

AbstractFacade

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.dao;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

/**
 *
 * @author DELL
 */
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

CategorieFacade

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.dao;

import com.mycompany.entities.Categorie;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author DELL
 */
@Stateless
public class CategorieFacade extends AbstractFacade<Categorie> implements CategorieFacadeLocal {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.mycompany_ProjetCommerce-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public CategorieFacade() {
        super(Categorie.class);
    }



}
```

CategorieFacadeLocal

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.dao;

import com.mycompany.entities.Categorie;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Local;

/**
 *
 * @author DELL
 */
@Local
public interface CategorieFacadeLocal {

    void create(Categorie categorie);

    void edit(Categorie categorie);

    void remove(Categorie categorie);

    Categorie find(Object id);

    List<Categorie> findAll();

    List<Categorie> findRange(int[] range);

    int count();


}
```

CategorieController

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.controlleur;

import com.mycompany.dao.CategorieFacadeLocal;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.ui.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("categorie")
public class CategorieController {
    CategorieFacadeLocal categorieFacade = lookupCategorieFacadeLocal();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap modelmap){
        modelmap.put("listeCategorie", categorieFacade.findAll());

        return "index";
    }

    private CategorieFacadeLocal lookupCategorieFacadeLocal() {
        try {
            Context c = new InitialContext();
            return (CategorieFacadeLocal) c.lookup("java:global/com.mycompany_ProjetCommerce-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.mycompany_ProjetCommerce-ejb_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOT/CategorieFacade!com.mycompany.dao.CategorieFacadeLocal");
        } catch (NamingException ne) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
            throw new RuntimeException(ne);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're probably not querying the database/schema you think you're querying. Or you forgot to commit the insertions you made to the table.

Comment: my objects are already persist in database , i want just to retreive them in a jsp page.

Comment: @BalusC I would agree with you if the OP attempts to invoke Spring controllers/services from EJBs, but I think that Spring MVC --> EJB should remain simple enough.

Comment: but I don't khow what should I do to make this work??